# Put a read-only string parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to display a parameter on the screen and make it read-only. If I put a string with a default value, the user can change it. Example:

```
string(
name: 'parametro1',
defaultValue: 'parametro1')
```

I have tried to use the following class

```
        [$class: 'WReadonlyStringParameterDefinition', 
        name: 'parametro1',
        defaultValue: 'parametro1']
```

But it shows me the following error

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class hudson.model.ParameterDefinition is named WReadonlyStringParameterDefinition

Comment: Parameter is something that can be set by user. If you don't want the user to set it, don't use the parameter.

Comment: @Victor did you install the [Readonly Parameter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/readonly-parameters/)?

Comment: I havent install the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Define the parameter as a choice with unique value.

```
choice(name: 'parametro1', choices: [ "parametro1"])
```